# Getting values beyond the limits of getdate() method

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var d = new Date("July 21, 1983000 01:15:00");
var n = d.getDate()
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

The result i get is NaN

How to get the value 21 ?

Comment: your year is invalid.

Comment: Adding to ^^^ `new Date("July 21, 1983 01:15:00")`

Comment: The `Date` object can handle years up to the year 275,760. That's 274,743 years from now. Why do you want to handle dates beyond that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think because *Date()* does the calculation based on milliseconds, you cannot do anything with a date in 1983000 as it will overflow anything. But we should be able to do these calculations in days ( not that big):

```
function BigDate(string){
  string=string.split("-");
  ["days","month","year","hours","minutes","seconds"].forEach((el,i)=>this[el]=+string[i]||0,this);
}
BigDate.prototype={
  hours:0,
  minutes:0,
  seconds:0,
  days:0,
  dayinweek:0,
  month:0,
  year:0,
  getDate:function(){
    return this.days;
}
//more to implement...
};

var d = new BigDate("21-6-1983000-01-15-00");
var n = d.getDate()
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
```

http://jsbin.com/vuxeqeqeho/edit?console

Comment: This big date method can be used on any length numbers ?

Comment: @VX7 if not one of them (e.g. year) overflows the max Number length ( very big) Yes.

Comment: @VX7 wich is the year: +/- 9007199254740991

Comment: @Jonasw 9007199254740991 is far too small. VX7 has clearly stated that he needs to be able to support infinite years. He has some very forward-thinking users who might need to schedule dates for after the sun has engulfed the Earth. :P

Answer (score 1):

Dates, under the hood, are just numbers. In javascript, that is the number of milliseconds since datum.

So your request is impossible. It would be like trying to feed in an integer which overflows the max integer and asking what the second digit is. It cannot be represented, so there is no option to read that digit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the date you entered is `null`, because the given `1983000` year is not a valid year number.

You can see from [Ecmascript Date - **Extended years**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15.1) that:

> ECMAScript requires the ability to specify 6 digit years (extended years); approximately 285,426 years, either forward or backward, from 01 January, 1970 UTC. To represent years before 0 or after 9999, ISO 8601 permits the expansion of the year representation, but only by prior agreement between the sender and the receiver. In the simplified ECMAScript format such an expanded year representation shall have 2 extra year digits and is always prefixed with a + or – sign. The year 0 is considered positive and hence prefixed with a + sign.

So the MAXIMUM possible year value would be `285,426` which is much smaller than the value you entered.

Here's a Demo with a valid year:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date("July 21, 198300 01:15:00");
  var n = d.getDate();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

**Note:**

Note also that your date `.getTime()` is higher than [JavaScript's **Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) which is `9007199254740991`, and the maximum possible timesatmp for a `date` is `8640000000000000`.

Comment: Actually, the maximum timestamp for a `Date` is exactly `8640000000000000`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:15:00"),
        n = d.getDate();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your date format is incorrect , check that link for finding correct formats : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

**Updated:**

Watch out your dateformat.
Try replacing below codeline with yours:

```
var d = new Date("July 21, 1983 01:15:00");
```

Comment: [You've posted an answer in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: No i mean the year 1983000 exactly

Comment: @VX7 why?? this will require a *very, very* big amount of math

Comment: I am testing values on a timeline i need it work on infinite number. When i entered this year i get result NaN thats why i ask for a solution

Comment: @VX7 the maximum year for javascript date is 275760 e,g.
var d = new Date("September 13, 275760 23:59:59");

Comment: Ok beyond 275760 what will do ?

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: @VX7 Why? Explain why you need to do this if you expect people to indulge your impractical question.

Comment: @JLRishe i am using this value for a timeline

Comment: @VX7 Yeah, you already said that, but it doesn't answer my question. Why does your timeline need to extend past the year 275760?

Comment: @JLRishe I need to enter events of infinite time. So if the user want to place an event on that purticular date it is not possible now. Thats why i asked this question. Sorry for any trouble.

Comment: @VX7 Yeah, you already said that too. Let's try this one more time: Why do you need to enter events on an infinite timeline?

Comment: Iam creating a timeline project that can be used for planning future projects just like we do in trello.

Comment: @VX7 believe me, none of us will be alive more than 275760 years so I think that should be enough for your timeline

Comment: @VX7 I don't think that you or your users have the foresight to plan projects for the year 1983000. You should be fine limiting them to a mere 275,000 years or so.

Comment: @VX7 And if you're going to compare your app to Trello, Trello restricts years to four digits. Unthinkable, I know, but maybe you should consider following their example.